# How to Spin a Sprite Node by a particular force like fidget spinner

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, 2d-games

I want to spin a sprite node by a particular force like a fidget spinner. When the user moves his finger on screen fast then the spinner spins faster and when the user moves his finger slower on screen then spinner (`SKSpriteNode`) spins slower.
I have an image of the spinner that I assign to the node. Also I want to check in which position it stops, as I have a list of items around that node and depending on where it stopped, I want to select that item. I know that I have to apply an angular impulse but I don't know how to calculate its value.

Like more force to be applied the faster the touch is (like a real spinner)

This is what I'm doing:

`fidgetSpinner.physicsBody?.applyAngularImpulse(5)`

Comment: What is your question? Is the spinner not spinning or is it spinning but with the wrong force?

Comment: My question is how to spin with accurate force on the touch movement or in touchesMove delegate of UITouch

Comment: So you want more force to be applied the faster the touch is? (like a real spinner)? If so, can you please edit this information into your questions.

Comment: yes Steve ,I want to move the spinner according to the user movement but only around its axis

Comment: Then you need to apply an circular impulse to the physics body, at a point, direction and value appropriate to the swipe.  You will need to read up on the ‘applyForce(_:at:)‘ method in the SKPhysicsBody class reference (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520032-applyforce) and also on swipe gesture recognisers in Sprite-Kit (https://stackoverflow.com/q/39783608/1430420) and how to extract the speed, location and direction of the swipe.

Answer (score 0):

angular impulse is the correct way to go,  apply force would move the entire body in a linear fashion.  Almost all physics bodies are done in the unit of Newtons/(seconds * seconds) (With the exception of applyForce,  this uses pixels due to a bug).  This is 150 points on your scene.

You just need a fancy extension to do conversions for you

```
extension CGFloat
{
   public var toNewtons : CGFloat { return self / 150.0 }
}
```

Then to use it, you just need to do

```
let distanceInNewtons = distanceOfTouch.toNewtons
node.physicsBody?.applyAngularImpulse(distanceInNewtons)
```

Comment: If the units of distanceOfTouch is pixels, dividing by 150 will give you distance in meters. The units of angular impulse is Newton seconds (kilogram meters per second).

Comment: I am not sure what you are arguing or commenting here,  150 points = 1 Newton,  do you want to call it 150 points per second?

Comment: Um, it can be both, a newton is for force to push 1 kilogram 1 meter in 1 second.  We are pushing 1 kilogram 150 points in 1 second

Comment: I am not sure why you are arguing with me, just do applyForce(150) and applyImpulse(1) and you will see the velocity of the sprite would be the same

Comment: Do you the difference between a force and an impulse?

Comment: Yes, applyImpulse changes your velocity immediately. While applyForce changes velocity over time,  in our case 1 frame. So basically one  assigns velocity before the simulation and one assigns it during the simulation process. Both take in a value in Newtons, so there is no reason that applyingForce should take 150x the Newtons that applyImpulse takes to achieve the same velocity in a vacuum physicsWorld.  This means that applyForce is bugged and not taking into consideration the conversion to meters.

Comment: I am done with you, you are now just trolling instead of providing any usefulness to your comments.