# Character jump up by swiping up in SpriteKit/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

At the moment I want to program a jump and run game for iOS. In this game, the character should jump up by swiping up. I know the character can jump up by the function: applyimpulse by touching on the screen (I also know how to program it). But which function can the character jump up by swiping up on the screen, or is there the same function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a swipe gesture to a node in spritekit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783608/how-to-add-a-swipe-gesture-to-a-node-in-spritekit)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

Add following variable inside your GameScene

```
// MARK: Gesture Recognizers
var upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
```

Add following lines into your didMove function like below:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))
    upSwipe.direction = .up
    view?.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)
}
```

Here is where magic happens:

```
@objc func handleSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .ended {
        switch sender.direction {
        case .up:
        // Call your jump function here
        jump()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.